# Using Like with additional criteria

Tags: sql

Seems simple, but I can't get any results with this query:

```
WHERE   
WKSHT_CD like 'E2%' AND
(LINE_NUM = '01100' OR
LINE_NUM = '01300' OR
LINE_NUM = '01700' OR
LINE_NUM = '01701') AND
(CLMN_NUM = '00100' OR
CLMN_NUM = '00200')
```

The wildcard works by itself, but when combined with additional criteria it returns nothing.

Comment: We need table structure and sample data to find problem

Comment: You need to post a bit more info. Have you tried it on a reduced test data set

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE 
WKSHT_CD like 'E2%' 
AND LINE_NUM in('01100', '01300', '01700', '01701') 
AND CLMN_NUM in('00100', '00200')
```

As long as the table has at least one row that matches all of your criteria, this will work.

edit: based on the sample data you commented with, try this instead:

```
WHERE 
WKSHT_CD like 'E2%' 
AND LINE_NUM in('01100', '01300', '01700', '01701') 
AND CLMN_NUM in('0100', '0200')
```

Comment: I am not getting errors with either version, but it is not returning any results.. Here is a sample of the data:

WKSHT_CD LINE_NUM CLMN_NUM
E20D180               01300 0100
E20D180               01700 0100
E20D180               01100 0100
E20D180               01701 0100
E20D180               01300 0200

Comment: If no results are being returned, that means that there were no rows that matched all of your criteria. What datatypes are your columns? Can we see the table design?

Comment: WKSHT_CD LINE_NUM CLMN_NUM
E20D180 01300 0100 
E20D180 01700 0100 
E20D180 01100 0100 
E20D180 01701 0100 
E20D180 01300 0200

Comment: Ah, in the sample data you left, CLMN_NUM is only 4 characters long. For example, `0100` instead of what you have in your query, which is `00100`. For the last `and` statement, try this: `AND CLMN_NUM in('0100', '0200')` instead of `AND CLMN_NUM in('00100', '00200')`

Comment: ah man, you are awesome! thank you!! sorry to waste your time on something so dumb.

Comment: No problem! You can close the question by clicking the checkmark by the answer that solved your problem. This will let everyone know that you've gotten the help that you need, and it's a nice thanks to the person that helped you! [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is useful if you're new to the site also.